# AWS - Have https endpoints for both www and non-www endpoints using Route53, ACM, Cloudfront

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53, aws-certificate-manager

I have a static webpage on AWS S3 with Cloudfront. Cloudfront is setup with ACM (AWS Certificate Manager) and am using Route 53 with it. How can I have both the `www.my-endpoint.com` and `my-endpoint.com` endpoints secure with `https`?

Here are some details:

- My ACM certificate is setup for just `my-endpoint.com` and is attached to the Cloudfront distribution
- I have a Cloudfront A Records for `my-endpoint.com` whose alias points to Cloudfront
- My `www.my-endpoint.com` is configured so its alias is `my-endpoint.com`

When I navigate to `https://www.my-endpoint.com` chrome complains of a potential security risk whereas the `https://my-endpoint.com` is fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a new ACM request for `your-domain.com` and `www.your-domain.com` (and better yet, `*.your-domain.com`).

Use the newly created certificate (after verification) on your CloudFront instance.

The redirection from `https://www.domain.com` to `https://domain.com` will work after you have a valid certificate for both domains.

Comment: Wow that did the trick! Changing my certificate's domain name from `my-endpoint.com` to `*.my-endpoint.com` was what I needed for both endpoints to be supported by the ACM certificate. I have a follow on question. I was expecting my `www` A Record in Route53 to actually redirect to the non `www` endpoint but it seems to just pass through traffic. Is that how alias works?

Comment: Actually when I changed the certificate's domain name to `*.my-endpoint.com` the `https://www.my-endpoint.com` was secure and valid but then my `https://my-endpoint.com` wasn't. You mentioned I should create 2 certificates but I don't see a way for Cloudfront to accept 2 certificates. Do I need to configure 2 separate Cloudfront distributions for each endpoint? Seems quite redundant...

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your initial suggestion. I created a new certificate with multiple domains. Thanks for your help. Could you answer my question from my first comment about how aliases work? I'm guessing they're just a passthrough so if my `www` A Record has its alias set to the non `www` A Record then it behaves in a passthrough manner?

Comment: @n00b You create a single certificate, but add 2 domains there. The first one should be `my-endpoint.com` and add another as `*.my-endpoint.com`. Something like: https://i.imgur.com/pzJnvCI.png

Comment: @n00b To answer your question, yes. You can also check the [docs here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-choosing-alias-non-alias.html) for more info.

Comment: Your comment has just saved my life hjpotter92, I have just wasted hours wondering why my redirect was not working and it was because I did not add the base domain name onto the HTTPS cert I created -_- CHEERS!